# Qt+OpenGl+SimpleGl

Tags: qt, opengl, webkit

I have enabled qt+OpenGl+SimpleGl on one of the ARM platform and was able to run opengl example programs. 
I also has a qt+Webkit, which is working with a graphic plugin.

I wanted to use simpleGl context for every thing, instead of using the normal graphic screen. So, when I try to run Qt+Webkit with simpleGl, I just get a blank screen.

Does QT support this? If so how can we make it?

Comment: SimpleGl is a egl plugin, which provides single fullscreen surface context.
http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/simplegl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. `OpenGL` draws directly to the `framebuffer`. The `simplegl` driver doesn't handle what is drawn using the raster paint engine of the `QWS`, so you may see only black.

Using `simplegl` for "everything" means you want everything to be drawn using `OpenGL` in your `EGL` full-screen window? This is possible under some assumptions. You have to write all your applications to be rendered using the `Qt OpenGL paint engine` (using the opengl graphics system is not supported under `Qt/E`). This is possible also for `QtWebKit`, I'm doing it now. Note that this does not mean that everything is rendered using hardware acceleration. You'll have to write your applications "the right way" to get all actually hardware accelerated. Consider that you'll have to handle the mouse pointer some other way in this case.

The other way is to just modify the `simplegl` driver to allow for the use of `Qt` applications using the `raster paint engine`. This is possible as well with some limitations. `Qt` can use blit to place its own windows over `OpenGL`. Look for the framebuffer driver inside the `Qt` source tree to know how to do this. You can then have common `Qt` applications and `OpenGL` `Qt` applications some way. I'm doing this as well. Not everything can be done anyway.

EDIT: I'm sure you already did, but in case, give this http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embeddedlinux-opengl.html much attention.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know anything about SimpleGL, but I do know that there is a way to render a standard Qt widget in a QGLWidget. Maybe have a look at this Qt Quarterly which I think is somewhat related to your question:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html